# Drawing on a 16 bit greyscale bitmap in memory

Tags: windows, delphi, bitmap, gdi

In need to draw on a 16 bit greyscale in-memory bitmap. Associating a `TCanvas` to the bitmap would be marvelous. I use Delphi but any language is OK. I just need the idea.

Any Idea ?

Converting the greyscale to RGB is not an option because half the resolution (pixel depth) is lost in the process.

Comment: I guess the underlying issue is: Does GDI support 16 bit grayscale images? Canvas is just a wrapper over GDI.

Comment: GDI doesn't support 16 bits per pixel AFIK

Comment: Drawing what? A polyfiller that can be used to draw many things with solid colors is just a few lines of code, but if you want to be able to fill antialiased TTF text using a interpolated texture things are different...

Comment: How big is your dynamic range for white channel? How about using true-color bitmap instead of indexed-color?

Comment: I am not aware of any library that natively works with 16bit greyscale bitmaps. The ones I know all convert to some 8bit per color RGB format. Since you don't want to convert to RGB, what do you intend to to with the bitmap after you have drawn on it ? If you want to show on a screen, then it gets converted to RGB anyway.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid writing existing functions already in Windows. Black and white high resolution screen are commonly used in radiography with Windows OS. So I guess GDI is able to properly handle grayscale.

Comment: I need to draw text, lines, polygons and circles as well as flooding a surface with some constant grey level.

Comment: After drawing on the bitmap, they are saved on disk for later display or processing. Display is done by converting greyscale to RGB using a technique allowing the user to zoom on a pixel depth (that is expand some region in the pixel depth so that it becomes well visible). Image are never stored converted to RGB.

Answer (score 1):

You could try an imaging library like ImageFX, or for an open-source one, try [Graphics32](http://graphics32.org/wiki/), or the [VampyreImagingLIbrary](http://imaginglib.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=down), according to its Docs [here](http://galfar.vevb.net/imaging/doc/imaging.html) it supports some operations like drawing lines and rectangles over an image loaded into a buffer.  I would expect scanner (image processing) libraries to support grey-scale images better than non-imaging libraries, but I don't expect scanner image processing libraries to be in-memory based.

But if you wanted to do the work directly in a visible buffer (You mention TCanvas), and you you are willing to limit yourself to Delphi XE, and Windows 7 only, you could use a Direct2D context, which supports 16 and 32 bit depths but as a 32 bit color depth is still only going to be 8 bit depth with respect to a grayscale image, I think that all normal non-greyscale graphics libraries are going to lose some information on you.

If you didn't mind using something a bit old, and a bit tied to Microsoft Windows, you could investigate using DirectDraw style (now merged into [DirectX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/directx/aa937781)) both to do the Buffer management (hold the 16 bit data) and letting you draw onto it, as well. I am not aware of it having any special support for 16 bit grayscale images though.

Interestingly, [WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105066/wpf-image-and-directx-surfaceformat) has support for 16 bit grayscale natively.  If you could find out how they do it, you could ape the technique in Delphi.  That link also discusses using OpenGL to do 16 bit luminance, but there's no suggestion from the question that OpenGL allows that.  I have found people trying to use [OpenGL](https://forums.codegear.com/message.jspa?messageID=226578) for medical applications written in delphi (16 bit grayscale) image display, but no reference to modifying the image in memory.

Comment: .. if you don't mind looking at non-delphi stuff, check out the Python Imaging Library (PIL). It can definitely do that, and read/write 16-bit grayscale TIFFs natively, etc.  It's used a lot in scientific/medical imaging.

Comment: Grphics32 (as the name implies) doesn't support 16 bit greyscale images.

Comment: ?? TCanvas does not imply any "visual" flavour.

Comment: I don't want to use an external library. I can easily implement the basic drawing I have. In the same time I don't want to reinvent something already in the operating system. I don't want to use an external library becuase 1) The code is fairly simple to write 2) The dependency is a risk 3) The cost of the library

Comment: It should be possible to draw directly on the bitmap then. But the cost (time) of writing even what started out as a very small graphics library might be a bit much. Seems simple now, but is it really?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Gdi+
it will not work on 16 bit grayscale but it does work on 48 bit RGB image.

so we can convert 16 bit data to 48 bit RGB data by copying the same 16 bit in all the three channels.performs some drawing and then again convert 48 bit back to 16 bit